# .htaccess Remove .php and add query string as folder

Tags: php, .htaccess, query-string

I have the following code to allow `.php` files to be accessed without the `.php`.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [L,QSA]
```

So

`http://domain.com/test/page.php`

Can be loaded as

`http://domain.com/test/page/`

I'd like to go another step further and allow

`http://domain.com/test/page.php?id=50575c76-a990-102d-b0ff-3bfb3c3a6c6f`

To be loaded as

`http://domain.com/test/page/50575c76-a990-102d-b0ff-3bfb3c3a6c6f`

The `id` query string is always a UUID.

I'd also like to allow other query strings to work. So for example:

`http://domain.com/test/page/50575c76-a990-102d-b0ff-3bfb3c3a6c6f/?a=1&b=2`

Any ideas how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a separate rule for the new URI you want:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options -MultiViews

RewriteRule ^test/page/([\w-]+)/?$ /test/page.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

# rule to add `.php` extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```